# Let $p$ be odd prime.Why $a,b∈\mathbb Z_p^×-{(\mathbb Z_p^×)}^2$ implies $a/b∈{(\mathbb Z_p^×)}^2$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, quotient-group

Let $p$ be odd prime.Why $a,b∈\mathbb Z_p^×-{(\mathbb Z_p^×)}^2$ implies $a/b∈{(\mathbb Z_p^×)}^2$ ?

For example, $2, -1∈\mathbb Z_3^×-{(\mathbb Z_3^×)}^2$ and $-2∈{(\mathbb Z_3^×)}^2$.

I heard the titled question is true, but I have trouble how to confirm this in general. I uses this titled fact to classify quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q_p$.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you know about the group structure of $\mathbb Z_p^\times$? In particular, can you express it as a product of groups whose "squares" can be determined very easily? Namely, what will solve all your problems is to know "how big" the subgroup of squares $(\mathbb Z_p^\times)^2$ is, or in other words, how small the quotient $\mathbb Z_p^\times / (\mathbb Z_p^\times)^2$ is. (Notice by the way that your assertion is not true in case $p=2$; that's kind of a hint; how is the group structure of $\mathbb Z_2^\times$ different from all other $\mathbb Z_p^\times$?)

Comment: Zp^×/{Zp＾×}^2 is isomorphic to Z/2Z, from here , what can I say ?

Comment: Well since that group has exactly one non-trivial element, doesn't that literally mean (among other ways to conclude) that if $a,b \in \mathbb Z_p$ are both not squares, their residue classes modulo squares are the same, i.e. there exist $x,y \in \mathbb Z_p$ such that $ax^2= by^2$? And now there's not much left to do?

Answer (score 4):

Once you know that
$$\mathbb Z_p^\times/(\mathbb Z_p^\times)^2\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,$$
then you know that you can write
$$\mathbb Z_p^\times = (\mathbb Z_p^\times)^2\sqcup x(\mathbb Z_p^\times)^2$$
for some (well, any) non-square $x\in \mathbb Z_p^\times$. Can you see how this helps you show that $a/b$ is a square?